# How to replace 0 from middle of string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a specific scenario where I have a data frame in which in one column I have text values like `'AZZZZ0ZZZZ'`, `'ZZZZZ0ZZZZ'`, `'BOMBAY 2.0'` and I want to replace the middle `'0'` with `'NA'`. If I use simple replace command the other strings replace correctly but `'BOMBAY 2.0'`.

I tried many different RegEx combinations but no luck.

- `df['column'].str.replace ('0','na')` - results in changing the `BOMBAY 2.0`
- `df['column'].str.replace (r'\B0\B','na')` - results in changing other values where I have `'nagpur'` to `'0gpur'`

Comment: Your second example makes no sense. Why would replacing `\B0\B` with `na` result in `na` being replaced with `0`?

Comment: As @MartijnPieters mentioned, the second example seems to be the wrong way around. Can you think of a couple of "positive" and "negative" examples? Maybe those would clear up the ambiguity.

Comment: You need to be more specific about the condition on when to replace and when not to. If your only concern is that the `0` neither is the first nor the last character of the test string, `df['column'].str.replace (r'(.)0(.)','$1NA$2')` will do the trick.

Comment: @user3554811, welcome to SO! please have a read through this, it will help generate more helpful responses for you and the community: [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

In the answer by *Patrick* it was assumed, that:

- before the `0` to match there is a non-empty sequence
  of letters (of unspecified length),
- after this `0` there is **exactly the same** sequence of letters.

I am in doubt whether your actually require just this, because you wrote
only about **the middle 0**, but did't write that chars before and after
should be the same.

If you don't require this, then be warned that this regex does not match
such text as e.g. `AZZZZ0XXZZ` (`ZZZZ` != `XXZZ`).

I, in turn, assumed, that you want to replace `0` with `NA` only if this `0`
is located between two arbitrary upper case letters.

To match such cases you can use:

```
(?<=[A-Z])0(?=[A-Z])
```

Description:

- `(?<=[A-Z])` - *Positive lookbehind* - the char just before is
  an upper case letter.
- `0` - The char to match.
- `(?=[A-Z])` - *Positive lookahead* - the char just after is also an
  upper case letter (fortunately, Python supports both lookarounds).

It will not match e.g. `0` in `BOMBAY 2.0`, but will match the `0`
in e.g. `ZZZZZ0XZZZ`.

Then you should replace **the whole match** with `NA`. So, as this regex
does not use capturing groups, it is simpler.

Notes:

1. If your requirement is that both adjacent chars must be letters, but
   **either upper or lower case**, then add *case insensitive* option.
2. If you have other requirements as to what can be before / after the `0`
   to replace, then change the lookbehind / lookahead part accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Simply open any editor (in my case notepad++), use the regular expression re =([a-zA-Z]+)0([a-zA-Z]+) and replace by $1NA$2

Comment: Are you sure? Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

https://regexr.com/3k753

Flags: CaseInsensitive, Newline

Regex:  `^(.*?)([a-z]+)(?:0)(?:\2)(.*?)$`

Explanation:

```
^   .....   $      from begin to end
(.*?)              catchall non.greedy ==> /1  and /3
/[a-z]+            any character (insensitive) ==> /2
/1                 backreference to 1st match of [a-z]+
```

Replace with:  `\1\2na\2\3`

This will match things like

```
VBNAAA0AAACC but not AAAA0BAAA
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have too much data you can try this approach:

```
data1=['AZZZZ0ZZZZ', 'ZZZZZ0ZZZZ', 'BOMBAY 2.0']


def replacement(replace,with_replace):
    final_list=[]
    for i in data1:
        data = list(i)
        for index, value in enumerate(data):
            if value == replace:
                try:
                    if isinstance(data[index - 1], str) and isinstance(data[index + 1], str):
                        data[index] = with_replace
                except IndexError:
                    pass

        final_list.append("".join(data))
    return final_list

print(replacement('0','NA'))
```

output:

```
['AZZZZNAZZZZ', 'ZZZZZNAZZZZ', 'BOMBAY 2.0']
```

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**: [`([A-Za-z]+)0([A-Za-z]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/j5ckM6/1)

```
def replace(text):
        return re.sub(r'([A-Za-z]+)0([A-Za-z]+)', r'\1NA\2', text)

replace('AZZZZ0ZZZZ') >> AZZZZNAZZZZ
replace('ZZZZZ0ZZZZ') >> ZZZZZNAZZZZ
replace('BOMBAY 2.0') >> BOMBAY 2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could capture a lower or uppercase character in a group  `([A-Za-z])`, refer to that group `\2` and repeat that zero or more times `*` to get the consecutive characters.

Capture these consecutive characters also in a group *(which I named `cc`)* and then match a 0 followed by a reference to `cc`

[`(?P<cc>([A-Za-z])\2*)0(?P=cc)`](https://regex101.com/r/yqR9bL/1)

Then in python you could use replace like `\g<cc>NA\g<cc>`

[Example output python](http://rextester.com/ARBHX66143)